# setText function does not change the TextView

Tags: java, android

the app runs the way I want I can see that in the Logcat 
but the text view is not changing and keeps the default value 
i also tried to change button enable status programmatically but stayed in the same , nothing get changed !!

I tried in the setText method both 
String.valueof(int)
and 
Integer.toString(int)

> java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         play =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
         Pause =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        hourstext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mintext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        sectext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    }

    void playb(View v)  {


        while (!ispause) {
            sec = 0 ;
            while (sec < 60) {
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                sec++;
               sectext.setText(Integer.toString(sec));
                Log.d("this", "sec value=" + sec);
            }
            sec = 0;
            min++;
            Log.d("this","min value ="+min);

           mintext.setText(String.valueOf(min));

        }

    }
```

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_x="274dp"
        android:layout_y="120dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="93dp"
        android:layout_x="217dp"
        android:layout_y="296dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="playb"
        android:text="Pause"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playbutton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:layout_x="63dp"
        android:layout_y="293dp"
        android:onClick="playb"
        android:text="playb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_x="139dp"
        android:layout_y="117dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="117dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i get no error message ! the app keeps working but no updated textView

i've included my XML Code

Comment: try whit settext(sec+"") instead settext(Integer.toString(sec))

Comment: i tried that too same result

Comment: please add the xml, I think that the textView might be changing but its not displayed in the layout

Comment: If you trace your code by breakpoints, maybe the issue turns up

Comment: i've included the XML

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to do with running everything on the main thread. You should never call `sleep` on the main thread or you will block the UI.

When the button is clicked you should start the counter on a background thread. You will then need to update the `TextView` on the main thread.

It can be achieved quite easily with RxJava:

```
private Disposable disposable;

disposable = Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(value -> {
            // Update UI
        });
```

To stop the counter:

```
disposable.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want make counter up for 60 sec you can use this code

```
long time=60;
        new CountDownTimer(time*1000, 1000)
         { 
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds : " + (time-millisUntilFinished /1000));
     } 
        public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!"); 
    } 
        }.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Before trying to fix this problem, let first understand why it happens

**CAUSE**

When you call View.setText(), Android doesn't actually set the text immediately. It pushes all of these set-text works to a queue on main thread to do LATER whenever it has free time.

Let's try to run this block, you will notice that until this while loop finish, View.setText() will not be done.

```
void playb(View v) {
    min = 0
    while (min < 1000000) {
        min++
        Log.d("this", "min value =$min")

        mintext.setText(String.valueOf(min))
    }
}
```

So in your situtation, actually the TextView will still be set, but you will not see the change until the while loop finishes.

**SOLUTION**

You should move this while loop to another thread, you can simply use an AsyncTask or a HandlerThread for that

Ex. Use a HandlerThread:

```
void playb() {

    // Start a new background thread
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("");
    thread.start();

    // Obtain the handler of new background thread
    Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

    // Obtain the handler of main thread (UI Thread)
    final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());

    // Create a runnable and send it to background thread to execute
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        public final void run() {

            // Do the job
            int min = 0;
            while(true) {
                int sec = 0;
                while(sec < 60) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000L);
                    sec ++;
                    final int currentSec = sec;

                    // Send the update-text job to main thread to execute
                    mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public final void run() {
                            secText.setText(currentSec);
                        }
                    });
                }
                sec = 0;
                min++;
                final int currentMin = min;

                // Send the update-text job to main thread to execute
                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public final void run() {
                        minText.setText(currentMin);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```